# how to use ST_AsMVT in CTE expression

Tags: postgresql, postgis, common-table-expression

as shown in the below posted query, i want to use `ST_AsMVT` but i receive error:

```
SQL Error [XX000]:pgis_asmvt_transfn: parameter row cannot be other than a rowtype
```

please let me know how to fix it

**query**:

```
WITH j AS (
 SELECT geoOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToTreatment,geoOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToBuffer,fk_gridCell_fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToTreatmentAsGeoJSON,
        fk_gridCell_fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToBufferAsGeoJSON,fk_gridCell_fk_site_selectedSiteID,fk_gridCell_fk_OpIndependentParticular_isTreatment,
        fk_gridCell_fk_OpIndependentParticular_isBuffer,fk_gridCell_fk_OpIndependentParticular_distanceFromCPOfTreatmentToNearestEdge,
        fk_gridCell_fk_OpIndependentParticular_distanceFromCPOfBufferToNearestEdge,ST_AsMVTGeom(
        geoOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToTreatment,ST_MakeEnvelope(6.741485595703125,51.12335082548443,6.74285888671875,51.12248887705868,4326),4096,0,false) As MVTGeom
 FROM Geo where geoOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToTreatment <> 'POLYGON EMPTY' and fk_gridCell_fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToTreatmentAsGeoJSON <> '{}' and fk_gridCell_fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToTreatmentAsGeoJSON IS NOT NULL        
 ), x as (
 select fk_OpDependentParticular_AoCForCellsRepresentativeToTreatment,fk_OpDependentParticular_AoCForCellsRepresentativeToBuffer,fk_OpDependentParticular_AvgHPerWindowRepresentativeToTreatment,
        fk_OpDependentParticular_AvgHPerWindowRepresentativeToBuffer from gridcellopdependentparticular)
 SELECT
        ST_AsMVT(j.MVTGeom, 'MVTGeometryRow', 4096, 'geom')
       
       from x,j,geo t1, GridCellOpDependentParticular t2
      where 
    t1.fk_gridCell_fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToTreatmentAsGeoJSON = t2.fk_gridCell_fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToTreatmentAsGeoJSON and 
    t1.fk_gridCell_fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToBufferAsGeoJSON = t2.fk_gridCell_fourCornersOfKeyWindowRepresentativeToBufferAsGeoJSON and 
    t1.fk_gridCell_fk_site_selectedSiteID = '202107090856' and 
    t2.fk_gridCell_fk_site_selectedSiteID = '202107090856' and 
    t1.fk_gridCell_fk_OpIndependentParticular_isTreatment = t2.fk_gridCell_fk_OpIndependentParticular_isTreatment and
    t1.fk_gridCell_fk_OpIndependentParticular_isBuffer = t2.fk_gridCell_fk_OpIndependentParticular_isBuffer and
    t1.fk_gridCell_fk_OpIndependentParticular_distanceFromCPOfTreatmentToNearestEdge = t2.fk_gridCell_fk_OpIndependentParticular_distanceFromCPOfTreatmentToNearestEdge and
    t1.fk_gridCell_fk_OpIndependentParticular_distanceFromCPOfBufferToNearestEdge = t2.fk_gridCell_fk_OpIndependentParticular_distanceFromCPOfBufferToNearestEdge;
```

**geo Data**:

```
Name                                                           |Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
---------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
geoofkeywindowrepresentativetotreatment                        |POLYGON ((6.632882377890264 51.12514810744214, 6.63288697266173 51.125058261186474, 6.633029746951139 51.12506115253025, 6.633025152456179 51.12515099879514, 6.632882377890264 51.12514810744214))                                           |
geoofkeywindowrepresentativetobuffer                           |POLYGON EMPTY                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
fk_gridcell_fourcornersofkeywindowrepresentativetotreatmentasge|{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.632882377890264, 51.12514810744214], [6.63288697266173, 51.125058261186474], [6.633029746951139, 51.12506115253025], [6.633025152456179, 51.12515099879514], [6.632882377890264, 51.12514810744214]]]}|
fk_gridcell_fourcornersofkeywindowrepresentativetobufferasgeojs|{}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
fk_gridcell_fk_site_selectedsiteid                             |202107090856                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
fk_gridcell_fk_opindependentparticular_istreatment             |true                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
fk_gridcell_fk_opindependentparticular_isbuffer                |false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
fk_gridcell_fk_opindependentparticular_distancefromcpoftreatmen|0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
fk_gridcell_fk_opindependentparticular_distancefromcpofbufferto|-99.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
```

**gridcell data**:

```
Name                                                           |Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
---------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
fourcornersofkeywindowrepresentativetotreatmentasgeojson       |{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.633172521264183, 51.125064043699844], [6.633177115459001, 51.12497419742407], [6.633319889519171, 51.12497708841026], [6.633315295600859, 51.12506693469526], [6.633172521264183, 51.125064043699844]]]}|
fourcornersofkeywindowrepresentativetobufferasgeojson          |{}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
fk_site_selectedsiteid                                         |202107090856                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
fk_opindependentparticular_istreatment                         |true                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
fk_opindependentparticular_isbuffer                            |false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
fk_opindependentparticular_distancefromcpoftreatmenttonearested|0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
fk_opindependentparticular_distancefromcpofbuffertonearestedge |-99.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
```

**GridCellOpDependentParticular data**:

```
Name                                                           |Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
---------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
fk_gridcell_fourcornersofkeywindowrepresentativetotreatmentasge|{}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
fk_gridcell_fourcornersofkeywindowrepresentativetobufferasgeojs|{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.6324540543343415, 51.12513943233803], [6.632458649935326, 51.12504958611004], [6.632601424153822, 51.12505247797637], [6.632596828829343, 51.12514232421359], [6.6324540543343415, 51.12513943233803]]]}|
fk_gridcell_fk_site_selectedsiteid                             |202107090856                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
fk_gridcell_fk_opindependentparticular_istreatment             |false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
fk_gridcell_fk_opindependentparticular_isbuffer                |true                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
fk_gridcell_fk_opindependentparticular_distancefromcpoftreatmen|-99.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
fk_gridcell_fk_opindependentparticular_distancefromcpofbufferto|25.28                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
fk_opdependentparticular_aocforcellsrepresentativetotreatment  |-99.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
fk_opdependentparticular_aocforcellsrepresentativetobuffer     |86.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
fk_opdependentparticular_avghperwindowrepresentativetotreatment|-99.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
fk_opdependentparticular_avghperwindowrepresentativetobuffer   |22.84                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
```

Comment: Can you share the create table statements for all tables involved? Preferably in a fiddle

Comment: @JimJones i added the two tables used. sorry i dont know how to create it as fiddle

Comment: The create table for `GridCell` is missing

Comment: @JimJones added it

Comment: SQL Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: @LetsamrIt have you tried `ST_AsMVT(j, 'MVTGeometryRow', 4096, 'geom')` instead of `ST_AsMVT(j.MVTGeom, 'MVTGeometryRow', 4096, 'geom')`?

Comment: @JimJones now i am getting:SQL Error [XX000]: FEHLER: parse_column_keys: no geometry column found

Comment: Your column/table names are unusually long and pretty hard to read :D next try: `ST_AsMVT(j, 'MVTGeometryRow', 4096, 'MVTGeom')`

Comment: @JimJones yes i tried ST_AsMVT(j, 'MVTGeometryRow', 4096, 'MVTGeom') but i get the error in the previous comment:QL Error [XX000]: ERROR: parse_column_keys: no geometry column found

Comment: @LetsamrIt the quey runs. see this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a0fc385ba3eef7fa5a7c91f30521db45). Please a few insert statements to the fiddle so that we can reproduce your environment

Answer (score 1):

The function `ST_AsMVT` expects a `row` in the first parameter, and you're providing a `geometry`. From the docs (emphasis mine):

> ST_AsMVT(anyelement row, text name, integer extent, **text geom_name**);

In case not explicitly provided, the first geometry column in the row is used.

> **geom_name** is the name of the geometry column in the row data. Default is the first geometry column.

The following query does exactly what you're trying

```
WITH j AS (
 SELECT 
   ST_AsMVTGeom(geom, ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096,4096))) AS MVTGeom
 FROM t
)
SELECT ST_AsMVT(j,'MVTGeometryRow',4096,'mvtgeom') 
FROM j;
```

**Note**: the geometry column parameter is [`case sensitive`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/master/postgis/mvt.c#L327) and it will only work if you provide it as lower case, as PostreSQL by default auto-lowercase the column names without double quotes. So, if you declared the result of `ST_AsMVTGeom` with the alias `MVTGeom` you have to provide it in `ST_AsMVT` as `mvtgeom`.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=95dc9523b8f2f3166d1f8666d739ba5c)